# Core Animation instrument - FPS out of 60

Tags: ios, xcode, core-animation

The Core Animation instrument in XCode shows the number of frames being rendered per second, but not the frame rate in a traditional sense. If nothing is moving on the screen, it shows `0 FPS`, not taking into account the fact that it's displaying a static image at the maximum frame rate (presumably 60 FPS).

Is there any way to observe FPS values the way that everyone else defines them?

Answer (score 3):

That is not the way things work. If there is nothing changing on screen there are no frames being rendered and so the frame rate really is zero. The screen still is refreshed at 60 fps but this happens always at 60 fps no matter if there are new frames available or not.

Comment: Right, but then there's no objective way to distinguish "low FPS because almost nothing is happening" from "low FPS because the hardware can't keep up", or to measure how code changes affect graphics performance.

Comment: And the other way around you couldn't distinguish high FPS because you are displaying a static image from high FPS because you created a smooth animation. Without context every measurement is meaningless.